# Html Speech Marks around link twice

Tags: html, hyperlink

In HTML I have a link that looks something like this:

```
<!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav" class="skel-layers-fixed">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Cyclone</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=“our-design.html”>Our Design</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="physical-factors.html">Physical Factors</a><li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="no-sidebar.html">The Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

When I run the link it errors giving me the message

```
No file exists at the address "MYUSER/site/""our-design.html""
```

With 2 quotation marks.

Comment: I think we're missing a piece of this puzzle...

Comment: What framework, CMS are you using?

Comment: try changing the link to http://stackoverflow.com/ and see if that works..

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` element in your document?

Comment: @Lal Not that doesn't work

Comment: @j08691 No base element. Wouldn't work as it is not in my <head>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (probably accidentally) using [Smart Quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_and_Unicode) (or "Curved Quotes"). Look at this code:

```
href=“our-design.html”
```

Versus this code:

```
href="physical-factors.html"
```

Notice the curly quotation marks - they typically come from copying and pasting hand-written HTML from Microsoft Word or Outlook (Office products automatically convert standard quotations "" to curved quotations “” for a variety of reasons).

Simply change this line to standard quotes and you should be fine:

```
<li><a href="our-design.html">Our Design</a></li>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Textedit created the smart quotes.